# Fill in with random Solr results, for related list

Tags: java, search, text, solr

I would like to retrieve some random resuls to complete a static number of elements with solr, the idea its to create a related list, in case theres no more related elements also show random elements.

So lets say, i want to get, 10 elements with solr, and my query its something like

```
name:Peter
country:USA
*:*
```

So then it will give ordered every person with the name peter from USA, lets say 4 users have those criterias, then the `*:*` will represent the fill in of the rest of the elements, so it will retrieve another "any" 6 elements, to complete the 10.
The problem its that i really want those 6 to be random from my collection, but its always retrieving the same ones.

So the idea it will be, first retrieve the elements that have certain criterias, and then fill the rest with random information from the collection.

Is it that possible in Sorl

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [RandomSortField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.html) which will enable you to sort results randomly.
For ordering the for the first few results, you can boost the criteria e.g. `bq=name:Peter` and try using random as secondary sort e.g. `sort = score desc, random_1 desc`

Comment: the boost criteria didnt work for me,
But the just the sort, did the trick.

Thanks